# Flow type - object of arrays

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have object like this:

```
{
  one: [
    {
      a: "some",
      b: "some",
    }
  ],
  two: [
    {
      a: "some",
      b: "some",
    }
  ],

  ...
}
```

What is the correct **flow** type for this example?

Comment: Do you mean https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/?

Comment: Link: (flow.org)

Comment: I've updated the tags, this should reduce the confusion.

Comment: @Adee See [the docs on objects as maps](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go

```
/* @flow */


type MyType = {
  [key: string]: Array<{ a: string, b: string }>,
};

function myFunc(obj: MyType) {
  return obj;
}


const myObj = {
  one: [
    {
      a: 'some',
      b: 'some',
    }
  ],
  two: [
    {
      a: 'some',
      b: 'some',
    }
  ],
};

const doSomething = myFunc(myObj); // No errors
```

#### [Live demo](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAodAXAngBwKZgCyWAKrgQLxgDeqYYA2gNZ5YBcYAzhgE4CWAOwDmAXQ4BBHjwCGWADzUw0jt37CANGABGK3oKFgAvgD51qQwG50UAK4CAxhj5wBYALZYAYnfsAKOFoAVhzEZPgAlDR0YDx4GDY8rgGBVoboqPYu3O5YAPJBYFS09C54HAzR9MX0NcpgAOSccG549WY1NToNTS1tlUbRIu1gGAhw5f3VHXWNza3DHV2zvQsD9EPmVhlZGGAAJnAAynMYABb6hTneDr4e+YHhFmDAwGAAcnBgeFJwPJzoQA)

---

### Documentation:

In [Objects as maps](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps) doc you will find `For objects like these, Flow provides a special kind of property, called an “indexer property.” An indexer property allows reads and writes using any key that matches the indexer key type.` with a dedicated synta: `{ [user_id: number]: string }`